# How can I set the location of a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, location, joptionpane

I have a splash window that pops up while the program loads. This splash window uses the method `setAlwaysOnTop(true)`, which is something I would prefer to keep.

The issue comes when a separate part of the program pops up a JOptionPane to notify the user they need to update the software. On Linux this appears in front of the Splash window, but on Windows it appears behind, barely visible to the user who then might sit for 30mins - hour before finding out why it's not loaded yet.

A fix I'd like to implement is to either

- Force the JOptionPane to popup somewhere else on the screen
  or
- Change the location that the JOptionPane appears at, so it is positioned to the top, or bottom of the splash screen.

The only function I can see that would do this is the `setLocationRelativeTo(Component myComponent)` method. But this is no good as there is nothing better for it to be relative to (and nothing present!).

Is this sort of thing possible? If so how do I go about doing it?

Here is my SSCCE (based off of SeniorJD's code in their answer) :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Splash splash =new Splash();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final Frame frame = new Frame("Frame");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                splash.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    Frame(String title){
        super(title);
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        add(button);

        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        actionPerformed(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Option Pane");
        optionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique gravida congue."); 
    }
}
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Splash extends JFrame {
    public Splash() throws HeadlessException {
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600, 450);
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
    }
}
```

This more ore less emulates the behaviour my users are seeing. How do I move the JOptionPane out of the way of the splash screen?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: no such thing as `J2SE` either. It's `Java SE` since several years now.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Are you OK? Hard day? The meaning is the same. Be patient.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not at the machine with the code and I rarely ever use that class. Regardless I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `frame` as a parent of `JOptionPane`:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JButton button = new JButton("Button");
                frame.add(button);

                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                frame.setSize(500, 500);
                frame.setLocation(500, 500);

                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Option Pane");
                        optionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Message!"); // if you put null instead of frame, the option pane will be behind the frame
                    }
                });

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, I have the frame set as the 'parent' and not null. If I include a `frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` to your example the message pops up to the side. I'll go and see what it is that make my situation different. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my question to show you my SSCCE, I hope that helps explain my situation!

Comment: @Pureferret Do actually need two unrelated `JFrames`?

Comment: No I don't, and I realised that when I started looking at the code. I was still wondering if there was some solution if I wanted to keep two?

Comment: You should set as parent the `JFrame` which would be on top at that time.

Comment: But I don't think that it is on top, as the splash is set as on top. I could fiddle it though I guess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32360/discussion-between-pureferret-and-seniorjd)

Answer (score 0):

if

```
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

does not show it for some reason nicely on Windows I would either set the size of it to be slighty bigger than the splash screen so it would be more noticeable or do as SeniorJD suggested.