# How to get the JOptionPane.showOptionDialog in the same monitor?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a working laptop with two monitors connected to it.
I usually run my application on Monitor two (which is an external monitor).

In my application I am calling a `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`, but the problem is that the dialog box always appear on the monitor one (which is the laptop screen) in spite of running and doing all the computation on the application in monitor two.

I even tried `getParent()` method but nothing worked, I want it to pop up with the JPanel through which it is called.

Here is the sample of my JOptionPane.showOptionDialog:

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(getParent() ,
                jsr, //object
                "MESSAGES",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,
                null,
                options,
                options[0]);
   scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
   validate();
   repaint();
```

This is very annoying as sometime I thought the application just crashed as there is nothing in the monitor one but actually there is dialog window poped up in the monitor one.

> EDIT:
>
> This is a new question, as I dont have any problem in bringing the
>   dialog box on top, I have also used the solution of `getParent()`
>   method but it did not work. My main problem is of the monitors, If I
>   am running an application monitor-2 everything should be displayed in
>   monitor-2. But this is not happening in my case.

Is there any other way to deal this problem? Or can anyone justify this problem?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the location of a JOptionPane?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294446/how-can-i-set-the-location-of-a-joptionpane)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau check the EDIT. It is a new problem.

Comment: No it ain't. That you got X monitors has nothing to do with how you set the location of a `JOptionPane`. Also, your `getParent()` method is the one of the component the `JOptionPane` is created in, which we have no idea of what it is from your question. If it is the panel or frame the dialog should be showing over, you should not be using `getParent` but `this` instead. Which ends up being a duplicate.

Comment: It should be showing over a panel, I have mentioned in my (edited post).
I will try using "this" for the same instead of getParent().

Comment: No it did not work, @JonathanDrapeau

Comment: Is the panel visible? Seeing `repaint` I would guess yes but there's no way to know for sure. If you want better and faster help, creating a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be your best option

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Testing");`, according to [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1362033) it should help.

Comment: I tried this, but the result is same! It did not work.

Comment: so, are you saying that even if you pass `this`, dialog didn't pop up on the same monitor as your `JPanel` and shows on another monitor?